# Cannot find sequences in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried creating a sequence for my table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18. I have a syntax error for some reason (although I have checked multiple times the syntax), but I cannot even find the sequences folder for my database. I have also tried not writing the schema name, but the same error appears. What might be the problem? Where do I go wrong?
[Here is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQz2l.png)

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of error messages or code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) - post as text here.

Comment: Is `hca_test` a schema name in this database too? If it is just the database name then remove `hca_test.` and try again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the SQL you ran, and the exact error message you got, as text, as well as details of your schema - if possible, a [mcve] which someone could run in an empty database and get the same error you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is just a client application that talks to a connected SQL Server instance in the background. So SSMS only passes your SQL statements to the connected SQL Server and shows you the results that SQL Server returns. Nothing more.

What is the version of the SQL Server instance to which your SSMS is connected? (You can check it quickly by executing the SQL statement `PRINT @@VERSION`.)

You should be aware that the CREATE SEQUENCE statement is only supported by SQL Server 2012 and higher.

Comment: Well, apparently I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (9.00.3042.00). I really thought that when installing SSMS somehow the SQL Server version will be installed with it and I thought I had the latest version. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft . . . Thanks for the update, I will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: 2005, @larisagg ? That version has been completely unsupported for about **8 years**. I highly recommend you get your instance upgraded asap.